# Linq converted to SQL for .All()

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq:

```
    var result2 = Psl_Pt
                .Where(w => w.PaslNum == 33979)
                .GroupBy(a => new { a.GroupId })            
                .Select(a =>
     new  
     {
            Publish = a.All(g => g.Publish)

     });
```

What is the equivalent of:

```
Publish = a.All(g => g.Publish)
```

From what I see

```
.All(g => g.Publish)
```

means:

```
publish = 1
```

Here is the select statement:

```
select groupid from Psl_Pt
where publish = 1 and paslnum = 33979
group by groupid
```

Please let me know if the conversion to sql is correct

Comment: is the way I have the sql the most efficient

Comment: It's a simple select with a groupby. Assuming that's what you want, I'm not sure how you fine-tune that.

Comment: From my linq statement, what does .All(g => g.Publish) equate to in sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`All()` returns true if all members satisfy a condition, in your case `Publish == true`. So a SQL equivalent would be:

```
SELECT groupid, SUM(NOT publish) as AnyNotPublish
WHERE paslnum = 33979
GROUP BY groupid
HAVING AnyNotPublish = 0;
```

You must cast publish to integer, if it's not.